# machine learning using R and randomForestSRC package

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest, survival-analysis

I'am trying to use the "surv.randomForestSRC" as the learner of machine learning in R.
My code and results are as below. "newHCC" is the survival data of HCC patients with result of multiple numeric paramaters.

```
> newHCC$status = (newHCC$status == 1)
> surv.task = makeSurvTask(data = newHCC, target = c("time", "status"))
> surv.task
Supervised task: newHCC
Type: surv
Target: time,status
Events: 61
Observations: 127
Features:
numerics  factors  ordered
      30        0        0
Missings: FALSE
Has weights: FALSE
Has blocking: FALSE

> lrn = makeLearner("surv.randomForestSRC")
> rdesc = makeResampleDesc(method = "RepCV", folds=10, reps=10)
> r = resample(learner = lrn, task = surv.task, resampling = rdesc)
[Resample] repeated cross-validation iter 1: cindex.test.mean=0.485
[Resample] repeated cross-validation iter 2: cindex.test.mean=0.556
[Resample] repeated cross-validation iter 3: cindex.test.mean=0.825
[Resample] repeated cross-validation iter 4: cindex.test.mean=0.81
...
[Resample] repeated cross-validation iter 100: cindex.test.mean=0.683
[Resample] Aggr. Result: cindex.test.mean=0.688
```

I have several questions.

1. How can I check the parameters like used ntree, mtry and so on?
2. Is there any good way to tune up?
3. How can I watch the predicted individual risk, things like what we can see when we use `predicted` of randomForestSRC package?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Need: [MCVE] and define what is meant by "tune up" and "watch the predicted individual risk".

Comment: Sorry for my bad English. I meant "tune up" for searching the ntree, mtry , node size and so on to obtain the better result (lower error). For predicted value, I was thinking about the predicted value as shown in the Rdocumentation (https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/randomForestSRC/versions/2.4.1/topics/predict.rfsrc).

Answer (score 0):

1. and 2. You can try as below

   `surv_param <- makeParamSet(
         makeIntegerParam("ntree",lower = 50, upper = 100),
         makeIntegerParam("mtry", lower = 1, upper = 6),
         makeIntegerParam("nodesize", lower = 10, upper = 50),
         makeIntegerParam("nsplit", lower = 3, upper = 50)
       )`
   `rancontrol <- makeTuneControlRandom(maxit = 10L)
   surv_tune <- tuneParams(learner = lrn, resampling = rdesc, task = surv.task, 
                         par.set = surv_param, control = rancontrol)
   surv.tree <- setHyperPars(lrn, par.vals = surv_tune$x)
   surv <- mlr::train(surv.tree, surv.task)
   getLearnerModel(surva)
   model <- predict(surv, surv.task)`
2. for today you can not predict individual risk in mlr surv.randomForestSRC. There is just predict type response